# Why doesn't this DIV drop down in the right spot?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html, position

Okay, here is the problem. I have an unordered list with a bunch of items. For each item, there is a corresponding DIV that will drop down when the item is hovered over.

The sample can be found [here](http://hjmenu.quickmediasolutions.com/jtest.html).

Now, it works fine unless you scroll down the page a bit *and then* try to hover over the item. Then it slides down further up the page than it is supposed to.

Here is the relevant code from the page linked above:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function doOver(num)
{
    $('#s' + num).position({ of: $('#m' + num),
                             my: 'left top',
                             at: 'left bottom' });
    $('#s' + num).slideDown();
}

</script>

...

<ul id="test" style="width: 400px; height: 25px; background-color: red;">
  <li id='m1' onmouseover='doOver(1)'>TestItem1</li>
  <li id='m2' onmouseover='doOver(2)'>TestItem2</li>
  <li id='m3' onmouseover='doOver(3)'>TestItem3</li>
</ul>

<div id='s1' style='width: 100px; height: 50px; position: absolute;'></div>
<div id='s2' style='width: 100px; height: 50px; position: absolute;'></div>
<div id='s3' style='width: 100px; height: 50px; position: absolute;'></div>

...
```

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the `position` method of the UI ..
the following seems to work fine

```
function doOver(num)
{
    var $m = $('#m'+num);
    var mPos = $m.position();  // you could you $m.offset() here (depenging on the overall structure)
    var mHeight = $m.outerHeight();
    $('#s' + num).css({ 'top':mPos.top + mHeight, 'left':mPos.left });
    $('#s' + num).slideDown();
}
```

Demo : http://www.jsfiddle.net/jnUsN/1/

Comment: +1 Although I found something that worked, your answer was **much** better.

Comment: Mind if I use this snippet in an open source project?

Comment: Thanks so much! I just integrated into my menu: http://hjmenu.quickmediasolutions.com/

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found something that worked:

[[view modified sample]](http://hjmenu.quickmediasolutions.com/mytest.html)

Relevant code:

```
function Position(item,parent)
{
    $(item).position({ of: $(parent), my: 'left top', at: 'left bottom' });
}

function doOver(num)
{
    $('#s' + num).css('height','0px');
    $('#s' + num).show();
    Position('#s' + num,'#m' + num);
    $('#s' + num).hide();
    $('#s' + num).css('height','50px');
    $('#s' + num).slideDown();
}
```

...and because Chrome wouldn't render it right on the first try:

```
$(function() {
    Position('#s1','#m1');
    Position('#s2','#m2');
    Position('#s3','#m3');
});
```

Comment: I know, it's ugly... that's why I like the other answer better.